# How to remove the grid from Linechart (Apexchart)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a Apexchart linechart , having trouble from the grid and Nodata of line chart options .

```
noData: {
  text: none ,
  align: 'center',
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
  offsetX: 0,
  offsetY: 0,
  style: {
    color: undefined,
    fontSize: '14px',
    fontFamily: undefined
  }
}
grid:{
Show:false,
row:{Colors:[‘blue’, ‘transparent’], opacity:0.5
```

When there is no data in chart I can see still the grid is been reflected in the div of the chart and I am not able to remove those grid line or change the Div since most are svg items .

Requesting for some solution to hid the grid and show only text of nodata

Have inserted the code pen to test the code where in the JS file you need to replace type:line instead of bar

[codepen](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/xYqyYm)

I am New to this chart format so someone can help on to provide a good solution since I found most solution not working for me

Comment: The link leads to 404 page.

Comment: Updated the link [Apexchart](https://apexcharts.com/docs/creating-first-javascript-chart/)

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/QDdms9

Comment: When nodata there in the chart I don’t want to see empty div not even the grid . Just a text message at the center No data

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the z-index for chart bar or do not use the opecity.

Comment: Not working it still shows the grid row of the chart , when the chart data is empty